# postgres: Querying across rows in multiple tables?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there a way to apply a single query across the concatenated rows of multiple tables?  I have several tables storing metrics data, where data is initially collected in 10 second intervals, but is periodically rolled up into 1 minute intervals in another table and ultimately into 10 minute intervals in a third table.

That is, I want to be able to do something like:

```
SELECT value FROM table1 + table2 + table3
  WHERE age(current_timestamp, time) > '2 days'
    AND metrics_name = 'foo';
```

I don't think a `JOIN` operation is the right solution here.  It looks like I can get the *result* I want using the `UNION` operator, which would look something like:

```
SELECT value from TABLE1 ...
  UNION SELECT value FROM table2 ...
  UNION SELECT value from TABLE3 ...
```

Where `...` is the contents of my `WHERE` clause (etc), but this gets messy very quickly if the individual `SELECT` queries are complicated (and fails the "don't repeat yourself" mantra).  Is there a different way of cracking this particular nut?

Comment: using `union` may be the best option.

Comment: using `union all` is possibly an option too, but you don't give us much detail to work with

Comment: What kind of additional details would help out?  I'm trying to avoid having to repeat a query multiple times when selecting across the concatenated results from multiple tables. I was hoping the above was sufficient to illustrate the use case, but I'm happy to work up an extended example if you think that would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a nested query with the `UNION` in the nested quer. And I highly recommend you use `UNION ALL` unless you want to eliminate duplicates, which you won't in this case, so use `UNION ALL`.

```
SELECT
    value
FROM (
    SELECT value, age, metrics_name FROM Table1
    UNION ALL SELECT value age, metrics_name FROM Table2
    UNION ALL SELECT value age, metrics_name FROM Table3
) AS All_Metrics
WHERE
    All_Metrics.age(current_timestamp, time) > '2 days'
    AND All_Metrics.metrics_name = 'foo';
```